# Wait for an async task operation to finish and continue the current async task

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have two methods that are running their code in background, and method1 triggers method2 as follows:

```
+(void)insertAllDataInDatabase{
    NSLog(@"1");        
    NSString *url=@"http://localhost/kalimat/get_all_artists.php";        
    //NSLog(@"url %@",url);        
    NSURL *urlChannels= [ NSURL URLWithString:url];                
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlChannels];                
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation 
        JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, 
                                          NSHTTPURLResponse *response, 
                                          id JSON) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) 
        {
            NSMutableArray *arrayOfJson=JSON;
            for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfJson count]; i++) {
                NSLog(@"2");
                NSMutableDictionary *songDico=[arrayOfJson objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *artist=[songDico objectForKey:@"artist"];
                [self getArtistSongs:artist];
            }
        });
        NSLog(@"6");

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                NSError *error, id JSON) {
        //DLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
    }];
    [operation start];
}

+(void)getArtistSongs:(NSString*)artist {
    NSLog(@"3");
    LKDBHelper* globalHelper = [LKDBHelper getUsingLKDBHelper];
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfSongs=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    artist = [artist stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //DLog(@"artisttt %@",artist);
        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?artist=%@", @"http://localhost/kalimat/get_kalimat.php",artist];
        url = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
        //NSLog(@"url %@",url);
        NSURL *urlChannels= [ NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlChannels];
        [LKDBHelper clearTableData:[Song class]];
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
        [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
            success:^(NSURLRequest *request,
                      NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                      id JSON) {
                NSMutableArray *arrayOfJson=JSON;
                for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfJson count]; i++) {
                    NSLog(@"4");
                    NSMutableDictionary *songDico=[arrayOfJson objectAtIndex:i];
                    DCKeyValueObjectMapping *parser = [DCKeyValueObjectMapping mapperForClass: [Song class]];
                    Song *song = [parser parseDictionary:songDico];
                    song.artist=artist;
                    [arrayOfSongs addObject:song];
                    //DLog(@"inserting...");
                    [globalHelper insertToDB:song];
                    //DLog(@"getting lyrics");
                    //[self getLyricsWhereArtist:artist andSong:song.song];
                    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AllArtistsSongs" object:arrayOfSongs];
                }
                NSLog(@"5");
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                        NSError *error, id JSON) {
                DLog(@"Request Failure Because %@",[error userInfo]);
            }];
        [operation start];
    });
}
```

Basing on the NSLogs, I want to have :

```
1
2
3
4
4
4
4
...
5
6
```

But I'm having:

```
1
6
2
3
2
3
2
3
2
3
...
```

Is there a way to order the execution of those methods? 
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're already calling `getArtistSongs:` from a background thread. If you want those to run serially, just remove the `dispatch_async` call from that method. You'd also need to make those requests synchronously; I haven't used AFNetworking so I don't know if that's available or how to do it.

This will work without blocking the main thread, because your calls to `getArtistSongs:` come from the block that's running on the background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    // All this code runs in the background.

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfJson=JSON;
    for (int i=0; i<[arrayOfJson count]; i++) {

        NSLog(@"2");

        NSMutableDictionary *songDico=[arrayOfJson objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *artist=[songDico objectForKey:@"artist"];

        [self getArtistSongs:artist];
    }

    // All code above runs in the background.

});
```

The 6, of course, will still print immediately after the 1. If you need code to run last of all, it goes inside the block, after the for loop of songDiscos, possibly wrapped in a dispatch_async to the main thread.

Comment: But executing the operation synchronously will block the mail thread, and I want that this process runs in background.

Comment: See my edit. The requests would run synchronously on the background thread, and the main thread would continue to run.

Comment: I have now different output: `1,6,2,3,2,3,2,3...4,2,3,4,2,3...` I don't understand that part `2,3`. Why it's not executing like `2,3,4,4,4,4,...,5`

Comment: I expect `1,6,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,2,3,4,4,4,5,2,3,4,4,4,5...`. I don't understand your 4,2,3,4,2,3... but I think it's most likely (and the 16232323 suggests) that the songDisco requests are still asynchronous.  Maybe you switched the wrong request to a synchronous one? I think it makes sense at this point to edit the question with your updated code.